# remove unnecessary swc in flash builder lib path

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

I am using Welcome to Adobe® Flash® Builder™ 4.6.

I don't want those flex things appears at the content assist classes list, I didn't use them at all. it's pretty meaningless. those classes seems appear at anywhere whether the project include them or not.

[image: my favorite content assist classes list panel]

then I did a check at the lib path and did some experiments but I don't know if I delete too over the top I will get into trouble in the future. for I don't know the exactly usage of each swc package.by far i only know playerglobal.swc can't be removed, or the compiler won't work.

if you know the details of those package, please tell me, so I can decide which files i can remove

[image: Actionscript Project default library swcs]

[image: default Flex Library Project's lib path]

Answer (score 0):

If you choose "New Actionscript Project" in Flash Builder, you won't get all those Flex libraries in your library path (only the ones shown in your second screenshot). Those don't contain the `mx.` packages so you should be OK.

Comment: Flex Library Project would add those packages,you can only choose one of them as image of 3.though i only use Flex Library Project to create library swc file,and you wont get rid of the mx class even if you didn't include them in the path.